# How Can I made Compulsory User Look up field on my Custom Object Page layout

Tags: page-layout, required-field

I have **Employee Custom Object** who will be having his/her own User credentials, so I want to add **Lookup of User on Employee Page Layout which should be compulsory / required field.**

Comment: Nielsh are these credentials to support multiple people in the org against one salesforce user licence? If that is the case then you'll be violating your terms of service with Salesforce.com and should re-consider the approach.

Comment: Yes, I have to create different Emp Profiles and assign them credentials to access the app platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **Employee Custom Object** layout, mark the User lookup field as required. This will display a red bar to show the end user that the field is required and will stop the record from being saved until the User is selected.

You get the dialog to set the required flag in the layout editor when you mouse over the field and click on the spanner icon:

[image: setting the required flag]

Comment: Oh ! Great, I forgot to go on Page Layout and just trying some funny things with Field Editing n all, Thank You Keith !

Answer (score 0):

What about using a Validation Rule.

Comment: Maybe you can elobarate a bit more on how to setup such a validation rule.

Comment: If you don't know how to set up a validation rule, then do a search on Google for "Salesforce validation rule" and see what it says.